# Using Nested Tags for Custom Tag Library

Tags: java, taglib

I am implementing a custom tag library that will output html elements, based on attributes values that are entered. For example, I have a tag structure that looks like the following:

`<util:functionModule functionModule="Z_UCES_UPDATE_NAME" cssClass="col-xs-12" type="form">
  <util:field inputType="text" field="I_NAME_LAST" placeHolder="Last Name"></util:field>
 </util:functionModule>`

The functionModule tag extends TagSupport. In the doStartTag() method, I read the value of the attribute "type." If it is equal to "form" then I generate an HTML element using the JspWriter with output like the following.

```
<form name="hello-world" class="my-class" method="post" action="helloWorld.do"></form>
```

This works great on it's own, but I need content in the middle of the form such as inputs, buttons, etc. For some reason, when I use the JspWriter to output the form html, the nested tags within do not output their html.

I was of the understanding that as long as I am returning "EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE" that the rest of my nested tags would be called and they could output their html via the JspWriter. Here is my Tag Handler code

```
//FunctionModule Tag Classs
public int doStartTag() throws JspException{
    if(this.functionModule == null){
        throw new JspTagException("FunctionModuleTag requires a function name");
    }

    this.startElement = this.createElement(this.type, this.cssClass);

    this.function = getJCOFunction(this.functionModule);
    this.functionMap.put("Function", this.function);
    this.pageContext.setAttribute("FunctionMap", this.functionMap);

    try{
        JspWriter out = this.pageContext.getOut();
        out.print(this.startElement);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}

public int doEndTag() throws JspException{
    String endElement = this.createEndElement();
    try{
        JspWriter out = this.pageContext.getOut();
        out.print(endElement);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return EVAL_PAGE;
}
private String createElement(String type, String cssClass) throws JspException {
    String startElement = null;
    if(type != null){
        if(type.equals("form"));
        startElement = "<form class=\"" + this.cssClass + "\" name=\"" + this.functionModule+"\" method=\"post\" action=\"callFunctionModule.sap\">";
    if(type.equals("div")){
        startElement = "<div>";
    }
    }else throw new JspTagException("type is a required field in the FunctionModuleTag");
    return startElement;
}
```

---

```
//field tag class
public int doStartTag() throws JspException{
    if(this.field == null){
        throw new JspTagException("The FieldTag requires a field entry");
    }

    //StructureTag sTag = (StructureTag)TagSupport.findAncestorWithClass(this, StructureTag.class);
    /*if(sTag == null){
        throw new JspTagException("The FieldTag must be inside a StructureTag");
    }*/
    String output = "<input type=\""+this.inputType + "\"name=\"" + this.field + "\"class=\"" + this.cssClass+"\" placeholder=\"" + 
    this.placeHolder + "\" ";

    try{
        JspWriter out = this.pageContext.getOut();
        out.print(output);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    return SKIP_BODY;
}
public int doEndTag() throws JspException{
    try{
        JspWriter out = this.pageContext.getOut();
        out.print("/>");
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return SKIP_BODY;
}
```

The work around for this that I have is to set a global variable in the functionModule Tag class that contains the html string that I want to output. Then, in the field tag class, I call the ancestor functionModule class and gain access to the global variable. I then use the JspWriter from the field Tag class to print the form element and any elements that are inside the form element. This will work, but I would like to get it working the other way, where the functionModule tag class outputs it's html string, and then moves on to the other nested tags and they then print their html string.

Thank you for taking the time to review my question!

Comment: Could you (1) show your code for the tag handlers and (2) confirm that the form content isn't showing up somewhere else in the output?

Comment: @ChrisGerken thanks for the reply man. Dude, I don't know if I hit the magic button or what but everything is all good now. Maybe I should get my eyes checked because it's looking like the html code was always there but was way at the bottom near the footer of my html page. Hahaha time to take the day off.